# How long has NSString concatenation been supported?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, cocoa-touch, concatenation

I've just come across this line in some legacy code I'm editing:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"data/visuals/interface/" @"backgroundViewController"];
                                             ^^^^
                                   "Oops, what have I done here?"
```

I thought I must have accidentally just pasted something in the wrong place, but an *undo* didn't change that line. Out of curiosity, I built the program and it was successful!

*Whaddyaknow? Obj-c has a more succinct way of concatenating string literals.*

I added some more tests:

**A simple log**

```
NSLog(@"data/visuals/interface/" @"backgroundViewController");
```

> data/visuals/interface/backgroundViewController

**In parameters**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://" @"test.com" @"/path"];
NSLog(@"URL:%@", url);
```

> URL:http://test.com/path

**Using Variables**

```
NSString *s = @"string1";
NSString *s2 = @"string2";

NSLog(@"%@", s s2);
```

> Doesn't compile (not surprised by this one)

**Other literals**

```
NSNumber *number = @1 @2;
```

> Doesn't compile

---

Some questions

- Is this string concatenation documented anywhere?
- How long has it been supported?
- What is the underlying implementation? I expect it will be `[s1 stringByAppendingString:s2]`
- Is it considered good practice by any authoritative body?

Comment: Note you need `%@` for each `NSString` you are trying to print or concatenate so `NSLog(@"%@ %@", s, s2);`

Comment: @PabloA. You seem to have missed the point a little bit. That was just a test to see if string *variables* (as opposed to *literals*) can be concatenated in the same way. The result, expectedly doesn't compile.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't try to give a solution, just saw `NSLog(@"%@", s s2);` and I  wanted to add that note just in case.

Comment: writing @"abc" @"def" is just kind of adding up constants... so it might not be even any method call like stringByAppendingString ...  more a simple compiler decision to make a @"abcdef" out of it... mich less "magic" than considered...

Comment: At least January 2014 (from an old experience test I got). But I don't use it. It's just to tell you that's at least older than that.

Comment: This "feature" is rarely noticed and rarely used because it applies **only** to string literals, not to variables.  Any concatenation that occurs is performed at compile time, by the compiler.

Comment: Compile time string concatenation came to `objective-c` from `C` from very beginning. But there is only few peoples who knows about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method of concatenating static `NSStrings` is a compile-time compiler capability that has been available for over ten years. It is usually used to allow long constant strings to be split over several lines. Similar capabilities have been available in "C" for decades.

In the *C Programming Language* book, 1988 second edition, page 38 describes string concatenation so it has been around for a long time.

Excerpt from the book:

> String constants can be concatenated at compile time:

```
"hello," " world" is equivalent to "hello, world"
```

> This is useful for spitting long strings across several source lines.

Objective-C is a strict superset of "C" so it has always supported "C" string concatenation and my guess is that because of that static `NSString` concatenation has always been available.

It is considered good practice when used to split a static string across several lines for readability.

Comment: Huh, it's curious that I've never come across it before.

Comment: Do you have answers for the other parts of the question?

Comment: @James: To answer one part of your question: the concatenation happens at compile time, no methods are invoked for it. It is very useful if you want to split a string over multiple lines without adding \ everywhere.

Comment: WRT: the other parts of the question: 1. `NSLog(@"%@", s s2);` is not compile time, just a malformed statement. 2. `NSNumber *number = @1 @2;` The `NSNumbers` are not compile-time but become run-time code and were added to Objective-C only a few years ago.

Comment: @zaph, thanks but, I meant the numbered questions at the end (which you have answered in your edit), not explanations for the tests I wrote.